# How can I improve the memory output from a Bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a script that prints RAM total memory in gigabytes.

Here is the script:

```
echo "scale=2; $(sudo awk '/MemTotal/ {print , $2}' /proc/meminfo ) / 1024^2" | bc
```

and the output of this script is: 
11.61

I want to add a string so that output of this script will be something like:

Memory: 11.61GB

How can I do that ?

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` just to read from `/proc/meminfo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `bc`; `awk` can do math as well, so you can add the desired string to the output of `awk`.

```
awk '/MemTotal/ {printf "Memory: %.02fGB\n", $2/1024/1024}' /proc/meminfo
```